# How does the euro swap for Greek debt work?

Tags: currency, government-debt

As I understand it, some portion of the Greek sovereign debt has been converted into "Euro swaps". Can someone explain in simple terms what that means? What debt was given to whom?

Comment: Could you please tell, from where have you got that kind of an idea?

Comment: @Gspia Why does it matter? If you don't know about the swaps, then you won't be able to answer the question.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I don't know about that kind of arrangements. There were swap arrangements way back along but clearly the question is not about those. I tried to check if there is something in the news but couldn't find anything on a quick look. I asked, because your question sounds interesting.